# Winsock - Allowing multiple clients with threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, networking, winsock

This is the code I have currently, and I'm looking into introducing threads to allow the server process multiple clients at once, however I'm having a little trouble understanding exactly how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Client:

```
int create_client() 
{

WSADATA wsaData;
SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                *ptr = NULL,
                hints;

char *sendbuf = "this is a test";
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int iResult;
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

// Initialize Winsock
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    return 1;
}

ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

// Resolve the server address and port
iResult = getaddrinfo(DEFAULT_IP, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
if ( iResult != 0 ) {
    printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
for(ptr=result; ptr != NULL ;ptr=ptr->ai_next) {

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, 
        ptr->ai_protocol);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Connect to server.
    iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        continue;
    }
    break;
}

freeaddrinfo(result);

if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Send an initial buffer
iResult = send( ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 );
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

// shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Receive until the peer closes the connection
do {

    iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if ( iResult > 0 )
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
    else if ( iResult == 0 )
        printf("Connection closed\n");
    else
        printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

} while( iResult > 0 );

// cleanup
closesocket(ConnectSocket);
WSACleanup();

return 0;
}
```

Server:

```
WSADATA wsaData;
int iResult;

SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
struct addrinfo hints;

int iSendResult;
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

// Initialize Winsock
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    return 1;
}

ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

// Resolve the server address and port
iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Setup the TCP listening socket
iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

freeaddrinfo(result);

iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

cout << "Server initalized." << endl;

// Accept a client socket
ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// No longer need server socket
closesocket(ListenSocket);

// Receive until the peer shuts down the connection
do {

    iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if (iResult > 0) {
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);

        // Echo the buffer back to the sender
        iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0);
        if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);
    } else if (iResult == 0)
        printf("Connection closing...\n");
    else {
        printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

} while (iResult > 0);

// shutdown the connection since we're done
iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// cleanup
closesocket(ClientSocket);
WSACleanup();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the listening and the processing parts.

So, your main thread will listen the socket, and when recieve some connection create a threa.

**The thread will accept the connection** to have the client socket, the read and process.

Pseudocode for you main thread:

```
while (true){
   listen the socket
   if any entry connection{
       create thread and process the petition
   }
}
```

**Pseudocode for you threads:**

```
accept connection and obtain the client socket
process it
close the client socket
```

EDIT:
PD: This is only a temporal solution, in any real life situation that have huge petitions this won't work well.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work! In a real life situation, what would be done instead? I assume you mean having so many threads handling x clients wouldn't be efficient.

Comment: I don't have any real experiencie using efficient methods, but I think this can help you to have an idea about it, http://vichargrave.com/multithreaded-work-queue-based-server-2/
Another idea can be having a 'pool' of petitions and then using eficient methods to balance the disponible threads use, pass 'works' from the pool to the threads and collect the results.